# Solving line intercept equation for exponential decay using two points?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I have two points (x1,y1 and x2,y2) that represent **points in an exponential decay curve** (discounted cash flows):

[Exponential Decay using varying Discount Rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VxKB.jpg)

The limits of my mathematics is using the linear slope/intercept equation to plot a line through these.

My (hopefully) simple question is: What is the equivalent **exponential decay slope/intercept equation** that I could use to plot a curve through these two points?

My aim is to determine the value of y when x = 0.

Comment: The equation for exponential decay is $y=Ae^{-kx}$

Comment: @Mike I added an example plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a relationship
$$
y(x) = y_0 e^{-\lambda x} \quad (*)
$$
If we take the logarithm of both sides, we get
$$
z(x) = \ln(y) = \ln(y_0) -\lambda x \quad (**)
$$
which is a linear curve.

From $(**)$ one can infer $y_0 = y(0)$ and $\lambda$ and use it to plot a graph of $(*)$.

Given two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, where $x_1 \le x_2$ the line $(**)$ is:
\begin{align}
z(x) &= (1-t) \ln(y_1) + t \ln(y_2) \quad (t \in [0,1]) \\
&= 
\left(1 - \frac{x-x_1}{x_2 - x_1}\right) \ln(y_1) +
\frac{x-x_1}{x_2 - x_1} \ln(y_2) \\
&= 
\frac{x_2-x}{x_2 - x_1} \ln(y_1) +
\frac{x-x_1}{x_2 - x_1} \ln(y_2) \\
&= 
\frac{(x_2-x)\ln(y_1)+(x-x_1)\ln(y_2)}{x_2 - x_1}
\end{align}
Then
$$
\ln(y_0) = z(0) = \frac{x_2\ln(y_1)-x_1\ln(y_2)}{x_2 - x_1}
$$
and
$$
-\lambda = z'(x) = \frac{\ln(y_2)-\ln(y_1)}{x_2-x_1}
$$
**Result:**
\begin{align}
y_0 &= \exp\left(\frac{x_2\ln(y_1)-x_1\ln(y_2)}{x_2 - x_1}\right) \\
\lambda &= \frac{\ln(y_1)-\ln(y_2)}{x_2-x_1}
\end{align}
This gives the exponential curve:
\begin{align}
y(x) 
&= 
\exp\left(\frac{x_2\ln(y_1)-x_1\ln(y_2)}{x_2 - x_1}\right)
\exp\left(-\frac{\ln(y_1)-\ln(y_2)}{x_2-x_1}\,x \right) \\
&= 
\exp\left(
\frac{x_2\ln(y_1)-x_1\ln(y_2)}{x_2 - x_1}
-\frac{\ln(y_1)-\ln(y_2)}{x_2-x_1}\,x 
\right)
\end{align}

**Example:**

[image: example]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OdH1.png))

This resulted in $y_0 = 4.33$ and $\lambda = 0.37$.

Comment: I appreciate your excellent answer. I have one more request if possible. I have been able to determine a third point. My question is: What would the formula be if there is a third point? If it helps, the third point is at the midpoint of my two original x values and is approaching the value of _y2_ while still fitting an exponential decay curve that will cross the y-axis. This represents the maximum error on the low side of the curve.

Comment: The above just assumes a straight line between two points. If a third point is used and exactly on that line, nothing changes. In general it is not and that means a line fitting step (linear regression) must be added, to look for the line that goes such between the points that some error is minimal. If you provide three points I can add an example.

Comment: Courtesy of your reply, I believe the question I am asking is: What is the maximum rate of decay for decay function that passes through two points and the y-axis? What would be the curve equation for this decay function? Using your example, I believe this is _x=0_ , _y=Maximum possible_, then your two points which are _(2,1)_ and _(1,4)_. I realise this is a different question to my original. Should I post a new question?

Comment: The points will lead some line and the slope of that line is the decay constant $\lambda$ (times $-1$). So this depends on the maximum or minimum slope (need to sort out the signs) and this depends on the line and this on the data. An example set of data points would be the way to go.

Comment: For some example points I used some real data. They are in _(x,y)_ pairs. _(8,2609)_ and _(39.14,0)_ are my two points, my third point is _(10,2148)_.  A second set of points would be _(8,972)_ and _(13,0)_ as the two points, with the third point being _(10,519)_. I am fascinated to see how you work in the third point!